# Dimension too large while using pgfplots with gnuplot and tikz decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I use the following code ( with MikTeX latest version and GNUplot 5.4.8 ) to do the parametric plot :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{% tikz
    arrows.meta,
    decorations,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.markings
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{
    fillbetween
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[% settings
    name=plot1,
    axis background/.style={
        fill=LightBlue!20, opacity=0.75
    },
%   no marks,
%   axis on top=true, 
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis y line=middle,
    axis equal image,
    x axis line style={
        Gray,
        line cap = round,
       -Latex[round]
    },
%    xticklabel=\empty,
%    x tick style = {
%        {draw=none}
%    },
    y axis line style={
        Gray,
        line cap = round,
       -Latex[round]
    },
%    yticklabel=\empty,
%    y tick style = {
%       {draw=none}
%    },
    restrict x to domain=-10:10,
    restrict y to domain=-10:10,
    xmin= -5, xmax=+5,
    ymin= -5, ymax=+5,
    smooth,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!50},
    minor tick num=4
]
\foreach \a/\b in {4/7,9/13}{
    \addplot[
        postaction={
            decoration={markings,
                mark=at position 0.68 with {\arrow{Latex[round,scale=2]}}
            },
             decorate
        },
        line cap=round,
    ] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
    set parametric;
    plot 
    -1*(\a)*exp(4*t)+(\b)*exp(4*t), 
    -1*(\a)*exp(4*t)+(\b)*exp(4*t)*t+
                  .5*(\b)*exp(4*t);
    };
    \addplot[
        postaction={
            decoration={markings,
                mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{Latex[round,scale=2]}}
            },
            decorate
        },
        line cap=round,
    ] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
    set parametric;
    plot 
    -1*(-\a)*exp(4*t)+(-\b)*exp(4*t), 
    -1*(-\a)*exp(4*t)+(-\b)*exp(4*t)*t+
                   .5*(-\b)*exp(4*t);
    };
}
\addplot[
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={markings,
        mark=at position 0.9 with {\arrow{Latex[round,scale=2]}}
    },
    densely dashed, line cap=round
] {x};
\addplot[
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={markings,
        mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrowreversed{Latex[round,scale=2]}}
    },
    densely dashed, line cap=round
] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However TeX complains : " Dimension too large " . I tried

- remove key `smooth`
- adjust the position of marking
- using TeXLive 2023 on wsl to compile

but still no progress .

I now consider using asymptote to do the parametric plot , but how to specify the domain of x and y when using asymptote ?

Comment: Welcome! Please, add the needed boilerplate code (preamble, etc) so that your code is compilable by cut and paste. That will greatly increase the possibility that somebody can dedicate some time to the problem...

Comment: Welcome! Have a look at section `2.6.2 Dimension Too Large Errors` in the pgfplots manual (`texdoc pgfplots`). Does your code meet any of the mentioned cases?

Comment: Code runs OK for me. gnuplot 5.4.8 + TeXLive 2022 on Windows. Very nice graph, by the way.

Comment: Thanks . I use the latest version of MiKTeX and TeXLive 2023 with gnuplot 5.4.8 , I just added those information to the description .

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I'm using TeX Live 2023 with `gnuplot` 5.4 patchlevel 7 on Linux.

Comment: I run my code on overleaf and it gives the same error

Comment: @YCH817 I think there's some confusion. MiKTeX and TeX Live are distinct distributions of TeX. You should be using one or the other. I don't use Windows and I'm not sure if you can safely install both but, if so, you'd need to switch between them in the same way that people switch between, say, TeX Live 2022 and TeX Live 2023.

Comment: @YCH817 I just copy-pasted your code into a new Overleaf document and it compiles without error. Have you tried copy-pasting exactly the code you posted here into a new document to test? See https://www.overleaf.com/read/hqnmbfmhzmhn for my test.

Comment: sorry I forgot to uncomment the `decorate`

Comment: @YCH817 Great! So is this solved or do you still have a problem? If so, you'll need to alter the code in the question so we can reproduce it.

Comment: yes I still have the problem . I just modified the code in the question . Really appreciate your comments

Comment: When x or y get very close to zero, one or more numbers increase greatly in precision (for position of markings??),  exceeding register capacity. Don't know how to fix. Set everything to fixed point, maybe?

Comment: Well ... I decided to use another differential equation to plot my graph . Really appreciate your help .